# Mockito's spy does not work along with AspectJ using maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, mockito, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have the following test class and I'm using Mockito's spy. By running my unit test using Eclipse (right click->Run as unit test) all tests pass which means that eclipse build process using m2e and AJDT works fine.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

@Mock
private AnotherClazz mockedClazz;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
private SampleImpl sampleService = new SampleImpl() {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
       ...
    }
};


@Test
public void someTest() throws Exception {
    sampleService.methodUnderTest();
}
```

However when I use maven to run the tests I get the following exception.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.183 sec <<<     FAILURE!
    org.sample.SampleTest  Time elapsed: 0.182 sec  <<< ERROR!
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Problems initiating spied field     sampleService
    at     org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl$1.withBefores(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class org.sample.SamplelTest$1
Mockito can only mock visible & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
    at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:123)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.SpyOnInjectedFieldsHandler.processInjection(SpyOnInjectedFieldsHandler.java:43)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:68)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.relayProcessToNextStrategy(MockInjectionStrategy.java:89)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjectionStrategy.process(MockInjectionStrategy.java:71)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.injection.MockInjection$OngoingMockInjection.apply(MockInjection.java:93)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultInjectionEngine.injectMocksOnFields(DefaultInjectionEngine.java:20)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.injectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processInjectMocks(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:62)
    at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:56)
    at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
    at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    ... 50 more
```

What is here the difference between the AJC compiler used in Eclipse with AJDT  and my AspectJ maven plugin configuration? Which configuration or phase am I missing here?

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Update: I haven't found a solution yet but I know why is this happening. The problem actually lies here on overriding the someMethod(). Removing the method override or commenting out the aspectj maven plugin solves the problem as a workaround. I cannot let AspectJ out of my project so I have to mock the someMethod() as well without overriding it (e.g. using Mockito itself). It looks like a bug for me but I'm not quite sure does it come from AspectJ or Mockito.

Comment: Is `SampleImpl` a final class? As you are assigning a custom implementation of it (by declaring `new SampleImpl() {...}`, but you then ask Mockito to also spy on this. Then Mockito tries to spy on the actual `SampleImpl` class and throws an error because the class is final.

Comment: No it is not. It is actually a stateless EJB which cannot be final because the containers also use the proxy pattern for EJBs just like Mockito for spies and the class cannot be final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is here the difference between the AJC compiler used in Eclipse with AJDT and my AspectJ maven plugin configuration?

Well, you use a very old AspectJ compiler and runtime from 2011 in Maven, but your AJDT probably uses a much more recent version. BTW, does your code really have to be compliant to Java 6? Anyway, that should not be a problem, but I recommend to use the current AspectJ Maven Plugin 1.7 and also the latest AspectJ version. You can still compile 1.6-compatible code with it. When I tried to recreate your situation with the old AspectJ version, the code would not even compile, but you have not provided a real [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), so I have no idea about your JDK version, Mockito version, JUnit version etc.

Try this Maven configuration in your POM:

```xml
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.6</aspectj.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                <complianceLevel>${java.version}</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT -->
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This works for me. BTW, please note the `<complianceLevel>` in addition to `<source>` and `<target>`.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thanks for the comment. Upgrading to AspectJ plugin 1.7 solved the problem. Apart from the maven plugin I was actually using the AspectJ 1.8.6 and all the latest versions of the Mockito (1.10.19) and JUnit (4.11). Now I'm actually curious to know what kind of problem the old plugin might have caused.